# marklogic partial update - ignore xml attribute

Tags: java, xquery, marklogic

I have a tree stored as one xml-document in the marklogic database, which looks like:

```
<tree>
 <node>
  <id></id>
  <title></title>
  <children>
    <node>...</node>
  </children>
 <node>
</tree>
```

I am using the java api of marklogic to perform a partial update to change a specific node. The children attribute should be ignored during the update process, because only the values of the node should be changed and not the structure.

First I used the [replaceFragment](https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/document/DocumentPatchBuilder.html) to replace a node through a xpath. But the xml, which is passed to the replaceFragment method, did not contain the children attribute. The result was, that the children attribute was removed through the update.

What is an efficient way (java or xquery) to update a node, but ignore one attribute, in this case the children attribute? I dont want to load the children of the node for the update, because of performance reasons.

Comment: You might want to amend your question to refer to elements rather than attributes. Attributes are a specific type of XML entity and your example has no attributes.

Comment: Sharing code snippets makes it easier to give accurate advice. Have you tried appending /text() to your path, and then providing a text fragment, rather than an entire element?